# Sorting values in a tree map with string and list bean as parameters

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator, treemap, comparable

Continuation from my previous question posted [Sorting a map in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422185/sorting-a-map-in-java/22422362?noredirect=1#comment34095578_22422362)

I am trying out a solution to sort a tree map  based on its values

Let me declare the Map

```
Map<String, List<Bean>> sortedBeanMap =new TreeMap<String,List<Bean>>();
```

i have created a separate comparator method to compare the values .

```
 public class MapSort {
    public static Map sortByValue(Map unsortedMap){

    Map sortedMap = new TreeMap(new ValueComparator(unsortedMap));
    sortedMap.putAll(unsortedMap);
    return sortedMap;
  }
  public static Map sortByKey(Map unsortedMap){
    Map sortedMap = new TreeMap();
    sortedMap.putAll(unsortedMap);
    return sortedMap;
  }
}
```

ValueComparator class

```
 public class ValueComparator implements Comparator {
  Map map;

  public ValueComparator(Map map){
    this.map = map;
  }
  public int compare(Object keyA, Object keyB){

    Comparable valueA = (Comparable) map.get(keyA);
    Comparable valueB = (Comparable) map.get(keyB);

    System.out.println(valueA +" - "+valueB);

    return valueA.compareTo(valueB);

  }
}
```

I knew the values should be of type string for the comparable to Work.But in my case , it will be a bean list.So how to get the comparator to work for my case ?

i am stuck in this for a while ..Any suggestions and ideas would be great .

Thanks guys in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework full code won't be supplied.

You are on the right track.  Do create a class for your objects and implement the required methods for Comparable.  You can decide what the "order" should be for two of your objects that have a list of beans: should on be smaller than another because the number of list elements are less; because the individual list elements have names that are "smaller"; or another well-defined ordering?

Comment: Are you referring to the bean object class with getter and setter methods.It is already created

Comment: If you have two list elements, which one is "smaller"  (how would you determine that?).  Note: don't answer with code, answer in English

Comment: Loop through the list and compare the list element with another to find which one is smaller..

Comment: Ok .. so now implement that "compare algorithm" in your compartor of two lists

Comment: I really liked the idea of questioning me on the logic.It allows me to think of it rather than providing the full code which will make me look dumb..Thanks a lot for that

Comment: Glad this path is helping you move forward